# Get __init__'s optionals args in a metaclass's __call__

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I need to track the values of classes' instances (to avoid have instances with the same values). I coded the following `metaclass`

```
class UniqueInstances(type):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, dct):
        dct['instancesAttrs'] = set()

        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, dct)

    def __call__(cls, *args):
        if args not in cls.instancesAttrs:
            cls.instancesAttrs.add(args)

            return super().__call__(*args)
        else:
            print("Warning: " +
                  "There is another instance of the class " +
                  "'{}' ".format(cls.__name__) +
                  "with the same attributes. The object was not created.")

            return None
```

So, I can't create two instances with the same values, for example:

```
class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


coor1 = Coordinate(0, 0, 0)
coor2 = Coordinate(0, 0, 0)  # Warning: There is another instance...
```

But, I can't handle optional arguments, for example:

```
class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

coor1 = Coordinate(0, 0)
coor2 = Coordinate(0, 0, 0) # no warning, but there are two objects with the same values
```

Because

```
print(Coordinate.instancesAttrs)  # {(0, 0), (0, 0, 0)}
```

So, I want to know if it's possible get optional arguments in `__call__` method.

Comment: Optional arguments are kwargs.

Comment: @Daniel, `def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs): print(kwargs)` is `{}`